# Console pgAdmin-like software

Tags: postgresql, ssh, console, pgadmin

I like the pgAdmin III GUI software, but the GUI uses more bandwidth than SSH console.

psql is not interactive, without menus, tables list, etc.

Does exist some interactive text-mode tool to connect to PostgreSQL ?

Comment: psql is pretty interactive - it's hardly just a scripting interface, and provides lots of visibility into the system with the `\d` commands, lots of info via `\h`, etc. If you're looking for a curses/nCurses style command line windowing environment in the style of Progress etc, there is none. I strongly recommend learning psql and getting comfortable with it.

Comment: So, I got to know the magic word for text-based interfaces :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no text-mode window-and-menu curses/ncurses style text mode interface for PostgreSQL; no ncurses equivalent to PgAdmin-III.

I strongly recommend learning `psql` and getting comfortable with it. You could use PgAdmin-III remotely as detailed below, but in the long run you'll be massively more productive if you learn `psql`.

### Use PgAdmin-III via ssh tunnels or direct connection

You can always connect with PgAdmin-III via an ssh tunnel or remote TCP/IP connection. That way you aren't transmitting all the GUI data over the network, just the PostgreSQL protocol data.

For ssh, do something like:

```
ssh -L 15432:localhost:5432 remote_host
```

then while the ssh session is open, connect to `localhost` port `15432` to make a connection to the remote DB.

This will work even if the remote DB is only listening on `127.0.0.1`. It'll also work if you ssh into a bastion host then connect to the DB server from there; just change `localhost` in the `-L` argument to the IP/hostname of the Pg server. For more information see the `ssh` manual, particularly `LocalForward` for IP forwarding, `ProxyCommand` for custom multilayer tunnels, and the `-D` option for dynamic SOCKS proxying.

It's even possible to use an ssh tunnel to connect to a server that's only listening for unix socket connections, by running `socat` to proxy between the unix socket and TCP.

None of this will work when you're connecting to a Windows host, but [`rdp2tcp` can be used to tunnel TCP over RDP connections](http://rdp2tcp.sourceforge.net/) for similar effect. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/130552/tunneling-a-tcp-ip-connection-through-remote-desktop-connection).

### Use psql

`psql` is pretty interactive. Though it isn't a GUI windowing interface, it's hardly just a scripting tool. It provides lots of visibility into the system with the `\d` commands, lots of info via `\h`, tab completion, paging, `\e` break-out command editing, and lots of other interactive features.

Use `\?` for psql help, and `\h SQL_COMMAND` for syntax of a particular SQL command, eg `\h INSERT`.